# PhantomJS node with external scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, screenshot

I've written a phantomjs script using node to take screenshots of a webpage. The page I'm trying to screenshot includes an important external script which adds variables to the global window object. ie. window.__components.

The problem is, this is never set. It works fine in a browser but it just dies in phantomJS. I've altered the script to inject the script before opening the page, I've added a check to make sure that the components object has been added before opening the page and still it fails.

Any ideas?

```
function injectExternalScripts(page, ph, url) {
    page.includeJs('http://external-script', ()=>{

        page.evaluate(() => {
            return window;
        }, function(result) {
            if(result.__components) {
                openPage(page, ph, url);
            }
        });

    });
}

function openPage(page, ph, url) {
    page.open(url, (status)=>{
        // errors returned from page 
        // window.__components is null
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only return primitive objects from the page context in PhantomJS. `window` and DOM nodes are not primitive objects and if `__components` is also not a primitive object, then you also cannot return that.

You can check if `__components` is set with this:

```
page.evaluate(() => {
    return !!window.__components;
}, function(result) {
    if(result) {
        openPage(page, ph, url);
    }
});
```